# Weka probability distribution in classifier

Tags: machine-learning, weka, probability-distribution

I am doing a machine learning project using Weka .What is meant by Probability distribution appeared in the classifier output in Weka?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming x your model output and x is the probability that an instance belongs in a certain class. The question is asking what is the probability density function of x.